# Tabula-py: specify parameters for tabula.io.build_options

Tags: python, tabula-py

I am trying to understand how the build_options function defined in tabula.io module and the java_options in function convert_into work.
To understand it I wrote my code with just the page options specified:

```
import tabula
options = tabula.io.build_options(pages="all")
dfs = tabula.io.convert_into('input.pdf',"output.csv",output_format="csv",java_options=options)
```

but  I get this error:
Error from tabula-java:
Unrecognized option: --pages
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

What's the correct way to use the build_options function?

Answer (score 0):

`java_options` expects list of string.

```
tabula.convert_into('input.pdf',"output.csv",output_format="csv", pages="all")
```

You don't have to use build_options.

See also:
https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.convert_into